# How to search within a text file for a substring using withAsync in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

What I want to actually achieve is to write a program in haskell . The program is a multi-threaded text file search engine by breaking a text file into a list of lines. Each line must use the function *isInfixOf* from the module *Data.List* which should be put inside the function  *withAsync* from the module *Control.Concurrent.Async* . The result of the  will say True if the word I want to search for is found in the file.

I know the following code is incorrect but I am on the right path. I hope someone fixes it for me:

```
import System.Directory
import Control.Concurrent
import System.FilePath
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import System.Environment
import Data.List hiding (find)
import Control.Monad
import Control.Exception

loop [] = return Nothing
loop (a:as) = do                     -- <4>
  r <- wait a
  case r of
    Nothing -> loop as
    Just a  -> return (Just a)



main = do
         let lines =readFile ("myfile.txt")
         let keyword="to_be_found"
         let asyncs=[]

         forM lines $ \line -> do 
                                     asyncs <- async (print $ isInfixOf keyword line) ++ asyncs


         loop asyncs
```

Comment: could you provide the error message you get? What have you tried, what have you looked at? please also note that name shadowing is should be avoided - if possible!

Comment: You appear new to the use of `IO`. I encourage you to read through a tutorial on this topic, like [IO for people who simply don't care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html), then take another stab at this.

Answer (score 1):

### About monads

Forget about the `IO` for a minute, while you might believe that `do` notation has to do with `IO`, that is a common misconception. `IO` is just a monad that allows you to describe actions dealing with the real world. Understanding monads is the important part for now.
To put it concisely, monads define sequential composition, or "do this, then that", which is evidenced by `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. In imperative languages, everything lives inside `IO` and `>>=` is the same as `;`. [Read up on how monads and bind (`>>=`) works.](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#eightfold-path-to-monad-satori)

### Some remarks

Specifically, you want to do a `fold` over a list of `async` operations with possible early termination.

Make sure you understand `asyncContainsPrefix`, as `fileContainsPrefix` is the trivial part. Essentially, `joinAsync False (\r -> if r then pure True else Nothing)` is a short-circuiting and concurrent version of `any`. The other part of the function is about describing the `async` computations.

### Code

I got the following to work... It uses [pointfree](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) style Haskell and is in (almost) [eta-reduced](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) form:

```
import Data.List (isInfixOf)

import Control.Monad (forM, mapM_, liftM2)

import Control.Concurrent.Async

import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic (monadicIO, run)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    contains <- fileContainsPrefix "to_be_found" "myfile.txt"
    putStrLn $ if contains then "yes" else "no"

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- API:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

fileContainsPrefix :: FilePath -> String -> IO Bool
fileContainsPrefix file prefix = lines <$> readFile file >>=
                                 asyncContainsPrefix prefix

asyncContainsPrefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> IO Bool
asyncContainsPrefix prefix ls =
    forM ls (async . pure . isInfixOf prefix)
    >>= joinAsync False (\r -> if r then pure True else Nothing)

joinAsync :: b -> (a -> Maybe b) -> [Async a] -> IO b
joinAsync z handler []     = pure z
joinAsync z handler (a:as) =
    handler <$> wait a >>=
    maybe (joinAsync z handler as) ((mapM_ cancel as >>) . pure)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Tests:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

prop_async_seq :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> Property
prop_async_seq prefix ls = monadicIO $
    liftM2 (==) (pure $ containsPrefix prefix ls)
                (run  $ asyncContainsPrefix   prefix ls)

containsPrefix :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> Bool
containsPrefix = any . isInfixOf
```

### [QuickCheck testing](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck)

```
$ ghci Mult.hs
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Mult.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ> quickCheck prop_async_seq
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any speedup (if not in general, maybe for some pathological edge cases)?

Comment: @Alec Haven't tested that... sorry. Perhaps for large files there might be improvements, but then, the performance might be degraded due to loading hue amounts of data into RAM - or perhaps not, due to laziness. Feel free to write a benchmark and get back to us =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you'd go about reading every line of the file sequentially. But here is a function to determine if a file contains a line with the given prefix:

```
containsPrefix :: FilePath -> String -> IO Bool
filePath `containsPrefix` prefix
  = any (isInfixOf prefix) . lines <$> readFile filePath
```

Disclaimer: The file will be read sequentially.